# How get relationship entity from findAll in SDN 5?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

For sure, a simple question but I can't find my answer.
How can i get the entities from relationships using **Neo4JRepository** ?

**Java 8 // Spring Boot 2 // SDN 5.0.9 // OGM 3**

There is my code:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "category")
public class Category {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = InternalIdStrategy.class) Long id;
    private String name;
    @Relationship(type = "MEMBER_OF", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Sport> sports;
}

@NodeEntity(label = "sport")
public class Sport {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = InternalIdStrategy.class) Long id;
    private String name;
    private String descrition;
    @Relationship(type = "MEMBER_OF")
    private Set<Category> categories;
}
@RelationshipEntity(type = "MEMBER_OF")
public class Membership {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @StartNode
    Sport sport;
    @EndNode
    Category category;
}
```

A simple findAll from my Neo4jRepository return all nodes Sport but the set categories is null

So, can you tell me what did I wrong ?

Thanks.

---

**Edit 21/08/2018**

I changed my classes like this:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "sport")
public class Sport {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = InternalIdStrategy.class) Long id;
    private String name;
    private String descrition;
    private Set<Membership> memberships;
}
@NodeEntity(label = "category")
public class Category {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = InternalIdStrategy.class) Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Membership> memberships;
}
@RelationshipEntity(type = "MEMBER_OF")
public class Membership {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @StartNode
    Sport sport;
    @EndNode
    Category category;
}
```

Now i've got this result:

- In neo4j browser, the relationship is called merberships. Why OGM didn't use the RelationshipEntity's type ?
- In my Rest service, using findAll, i still get null on this set.

Nope, it's ok here :) I've just forgot to keep @Relationship on my nodes

Another Question: How do I work with this Optional given by Neo4jRepository.findById, did someone have a good article for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a direct relationship between `Category` and `Sport` called *MEMBER_OF* but also define a rich relationship (`@RelationshipEntity`) with the same name.
Neo4j-OGM does not know what to map in this case.

From what I see in the sample code it is not necessary to add the rich relationship class at all because there are no additional properties defined and this would be the only reason to create such a class.

If you have properties defined but just not listed in the example, you should change the type of your collections and set it to `Membership` in both classes.

Comment: Ok, thanks i will test it tonight (France :)) I'll come back to you

Comment: Still have the problem with your solution.